# How to validate the summation of textboxes values in the client side

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, validation, customvalidator

If I have Group of textboxes Say Group one , and another group of textboxes say group two .both of them in Edit Template of Grid view now i want to validate the the summation of the first group equal the summation of the second group in client side to allow save or add .

---

EX:

```
txt1 
txt2 
txt3
txt4
```

I want to validate that :

```
   Decimal.Parse(txt1.Text)+ Decimal.Parse(txt2.Text) = Decimal.Parse(txt3.Text )+ Decimal.Parse(txt4.Text)
```

**Note:**

> one or more of these text boxes may be empty and in this case i
>   consider the value `0`

---

How to do some thing like that using asp.net validators .

Comment: Do you want to compare the string concatenations or do the textboxes contain numbers and you want to compare the additions ?

Comment: @MatiasCicero : i want to compare the summations of values of these textboxes not the string concatenations .

Comment: you need to be more specific in regards to what you want.. if you are wanting to validate the string values of the textboxes as integers then you need to do a check converting the text box values into Int and assigning a variable to hold the summation of `var grpOneSum = Convert.ToInt32(txt1.Txex) + Convert.ToInt32(txt2.Text)...etc` also show us an example of what the values in each textbox will hold.. or use `CustonVailidtors`

Comment: @MethodMan : i have edited the question ,according to your note.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CustomValidators.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator.aspx

Below a little example to get you started. You can expand `myCustomValidation` to include checking for non-integer values, min-max ranges etc.

```
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" ValidationGroup="myGroup"></asp:TextBox>
    <br />
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" ValidationGroup="myGroup"></asp:TextBox>
    <br />
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" ValidationGroup="myGroup"></asp:TextBox>
    <br />
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server" ValidationGroup="myGroup"></asp:TextBox>
    <br /><br />
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" ValidationGroup="myGroup" />
    <br />
    <asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Error adding TextBox values" ValidationGroup="myGroup" ClientValidationFunction="myCustomValidation"></asp:CustomValidator>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function myCustomValidation(oSrc, args) {
            var tb1 = document.getElementById('<%=TextBox1.ClientID %>').value;
            var tb2 = document.getElementById('<%=TextBox2.ClientID %>').value;
            var tb3 = document.getElementById('<%=TextBox3.ClientID %>').value;
            var tb4 = document.getElementById('<%=TextBox4.ClientID %>').value;

            if (tb1 == "" || tb2 == "" || tb3 == "" || tb4 == "") {
                //to make sure the validator fires if one or more textboxes are left empty
                args.IsValid = false;
            } else if (((tb1 + tb2) == (tb3 + tb4))) {
                args.IsValid = true;
            } else {
                args.IsValid = false;
            }
        }
    </script>
```